# Mongoose `findOneAndUpdate` returns the updated document but does not update the actual document in database. [all fields do exist in schema]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update an object inside of an array in mongoDB. But what happens is -- it returns the correct updated result, BUT it does not update the actual document in DB.

It is weird, I am using this query from past so many months and it is behaving weirdly of sudden.

**Schema:**

```
{
  name: String,
  donations: [
    {
      assigned: Boolean
    }
  ]

}
```

**My Query:**

```
const updated = await DonationModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id:'document Object Id',
    'donations._id': 'Object Id of donation Object'
  },
  {
    'donations.$.assigned': true,
  },
  {
    new: true
  }
);

// Here I get the updated result
// But this is NOT updated in DB.
console.log(updated);
```

Comment: Hi @sachin , I am currently experiencing the same issue. Sometimes it updates and sometimes it doesn't. Did you eventually figure out what was wrong?

Comment: Hey @FiyinAkinsiku , sorry for the delayed reply. I defaulted back to `doc.save()`. I did not face these issues in the transactions done using `save()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `upsert: true` to bottem of to `new: true`.

Like this:

```html
const updated = await DonationModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id:'document Object Id',
    'donations._id': 'Object Id of donation Object'
  },
  {
    'donations.$.assigned': true,
  },
  {
    new: true,
    upsert: true
  }
);

// Here I get the updated result
// But this is NOT updated in DB.
console.log(updated);
```

Comment: Setting upsert to true will create a new document and I do not want that. So I believe this will not help.

Comment: Upser is not create new documet upsert creates a new document if no documents match the query.

Comment: Yes, but I do not want that behaviour in this case.

Comment: Maybe you can try updateOne instead of findOneAndUpdate

Comment: Yes, I can use that. But I want to understand what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're missing the `donations._id` in your donations object in the schema.

Also, use `{upsert: true}` instead of `new`, unless you mean `returnNewDocument`?

Working playground example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/0bcjdi5st40

Positional update documentation is [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Comment: `donation._id` is automatically created by mongoDB. I need not to include it in my schema. For every nested object, mongoDB creates `_id` by default. Setting upsert to true will create a new document if it does not find it, which I do not want in this case.